# awk - Filter a file with 2 other files

Tags: linux, performance, shell, awk, filter

```
$ cat arquivo1.txt
6|1000|121|999
1|1000|2000|3001
2|1000|2000|3001
3|2000|11|11
4| 100|22|1
5|1000|2000|4000
1000|10|11|12

$ cat arquivo2.txt
5
1000
7

$ cat arquivo3.txt
20
```

I want to output all lines from arquivo1.txt that the second field (arquivo1.txt) is not in arquivo2.txt and the substring(first 2 chars) of the second field (arquivo1.txt) not in arquivo3.txt.

In this example, the output would be:

```
4| 100|22|1
1000|10|11|12
```

So, I did the filter of arquivo2.txt:

```
$ awk -F'|' 'FNR==NR { a[$1]; next } !($2 in a)' arquivo2.txt arquivo1.txt
```

And I did the filter of arquivo3.txt:

```
$ awk -F'|' 'FNR==NR { a[$1]; next } !(substr($2,1,2) in a)' arquivo3.txt arquivo1.txt
```

Is it possible to have these commands together in one line of code?

All I need is performance, because these files are big (arquivo1.txt have 1 million lines and arquivo2.txt and arquivo3.txt have 200k lines each), is this the best approach to achieve the best response time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a kind of solution but it is for [gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk) ([awk](/questions/tagged/awk) solution at the end of this post). Maybe it is usable.

To use a hash is a good idea to make the searching in constant time.

```
awk -F\| '
  ARGIND == 1 {a[$1]=1;next}
  ARGIND == 2 {b[$1]=1;next}
  !($2 in a) && !(substr($2,1,2) in  b)
' arquivo2.txt arquivo3.txt arquivo1.txt
```

Output:

```
4| 100|22|1
1000|10|11|12
```

I did some measurements. I generated the 3 files with the following [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) script:

```
time awk ' BEGIN {
  for(i=0;i<1000000;++i) print i"|"i"|1000|123">"arquivo1.txt"
  for(i=0;i<200000;++i) print (i*10)>"arquivo2.txt"
  for(i=0;i<200000;++i) print (i*10+5)>"arquivo3.txt"
}' || exit 1
```

Then I measured the time needed to run the second script adding `time` before [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) and I redirected the output to `/dev/null` not to measure the screening. Here is the result of three independent runs:

```
$./test.sh
real    0m2.880s
user    0m2.816s
sys     0m0.044s
$./test.sh
real    0m2.931s
user    0m2.892s
sys     0m0.032s
$./test.sh
real    0m2.924s
user    0m2.864s
sys     0m0.040s
```

(The creation of tables finished in 1.5 sec). For 1 million rows for the input table, and 2x200_000 rows for the filter tables finishes in 3 sec and it prints 809_999 lines (at least so many times both conditions are evaluated).

Is something You expected, or it is still to much for runtime? My machine is a little bit old laptop with `Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU   T4300  @ 2.10GHz` CPU.

**ADDED**

Here is a little bit faster and real [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) solution:

```
awk -F\| '
BEGIN {
  while((getline<"arquivo2.txt")>0) a[$0];
  while((getline<"arquivo3.txt")>0) b[$0];
}
!($2 in a) && !(substr($2,1,2) in  b)
' arquivo1.txt
```

For the big test files the run time is:

```
real    0m2.544s
user    0m2.452s
sys     0m0.048s

real    0m2.458s
user    0m2.420s
sys     0m0.032s

real    0m2.493s
user    0m2.448s
sys     0m0.036s
```

So this runs in 2.5 sec.

I hope this helps a bit!

Comment: No need for the assignments; it's sufficient to simply define the key: `a[$1]`.

Comment: @TomFenech: You are right! IMHO this version is a little bit less cryptic... ;)

Comment: Your `getline` script will probably hang in an infinite loop if it fails to open either file. Please read http://awk.info/?tip/getline and make sure you fully understand all the caveats if you're considering using getline (and then, usually, don't!).

Comment: @EdMorton: Thanks for the comment. Neither of my solutions are fully flagged. More should be known about the environment. This [tag:awk] may be embedded into a [tag:bash] script and this can be checked easily, like `[ -f arquivo2.txt -a -f arquivo3.txt ] || exit 1`. Or even more checking can be done. But it depends on the goals of the complete task. Anyway I fixed it! Thanks!

Comment: @TrueY, 
"Is something You expected, or it is still to much for runtime?"
It's nice. I have a server with 70 core cpu. hehe

Thanks,

Comment: @TrueY just code the getline calls correctly and it'll remove the problem, see that reference I provided. The code you now have does not solve the problem, you need to parenthesize appropriately. In this case, of course, you absolutely do not need getline at all. BTW the phrase is `fully fledged`, not `fully flagged`. I notice you'd used that previously too or I wouldn't have mentioned it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk 
BEGIN{ FS="|" }
ARGIND==1 { f2[$0]; next }
ARGIND==2 { f3[$0]; next }
$2 in f2 { next }
substr($2,1,2) in f3 { next }
{ print }

$ awk -f tst.awk arquivo2.txt arquivo3.txt arquivo1.txt
4| 100|22|1
1000|10|11|12
```

the above uses GNU awk for ARGIND - if you don't have gawk add a line at the top that says `FNR==1{++ARGIND}`.

I kept the conditions separate for readability and in case you need to add more or change them later. They can be combined of course and negated if you want an implicit rather than explicit print.

Comment: Nice.  I hadn't thought of that solution for `++ARGIND` in non-GNU awk.

Comment: +1 I was just finishing off an answer to find that you'd already posted one. Mine was pretty similar!

Comment: @ghoti yeah that workaround fails if there's empty files but usually it's fine. The alternative is `FILENAME == ARGV[1]` etc...

Answer (score 0):

The `FNR==NR` allows you to differentiate between the "first" file and the "not-first" file.  If you want to tell the difference between three files, you need a way to identify them.  As other answers have suggested, you can do this using `ARGIND` in gawk (or a fake `ARGIND` per Ed's answer).

But there are of course other options.  One is to read multiple files within the awk script.  I'm not clear on whether your `arquivo3.txt` file is always only one line, but assuming it is, this might work:

```
awk -F'|' '
  BEGIN {
    while (getline < "arquivo2.txt") {
      two[$1];
    }
    getline three < "arquivo3.txt";
  }

  !($2 in two) && $2 !~ three
' arquivo1.txt
```

You can of course put this all on one line if you want.

If the `arquivo3.txt` file could contain multiple strings, all of which need to be checked, then you could loop through the values to set your condition.  (I won't write it out unless you say that this is what you're looking for.)

Comment: Your script will probably hang in an infinite loop if it fails to open the 2.txt file since on [some?] failures to open the file getline will return a negative value which the while loop condition will accept as non-zero and continue trying forever. Please read http://awk.info/?tip/getline and make sure you fully understand all the caveats if you're considering using getline (and then, usually, don't!).